# How to change the shutdown message for Windows using python?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a program which shuts down my computer, but I want to change the message that is displayed. Currently, it says that my computer will shut down in one minute; this is in a messagebox. Is there any way of doing this? Also, as 'extra credit' is it at all possible for me to have a live countdown? (60 sec, 59 sec, 58 sec...?)

My current shutdown code is this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-f", "-r", "-t", "10"])
```

I would like the message to be embedded in the subprocess commands.

Specs:

Python 2.7.3
Windows 7, 32 bit

Comment: I believe the flag `-c "MESSAGE HERE"` works. So `["shutdown", "-f", "-r", "-t", "10", "-c \"MESSAGE HERE\""]`?

Comment: Instead of coming to SO to ask question after question about each flag of the `shutdown` command (which takes you an hour to get an answer), why not either read the docs at MSDN or type `help shutdown` at your console?

Comment: @adchilds I just tried `["shutdown", "-f", "-r", "-t", "10", "-c \"MESSAGE HERE\""]` and it did not work. Instead, I got a command prompt console which appeared and then disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-f", "-r", "-t", "10", "-c", '"MESSAGE HERE"'])
```

Comment: Why do you need the -f? I was able to do the same thing without it.