# General Python socket questions with several answers

Tags: python, sockets, operating-system

I am trying to use [an example](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Sockets-in-Python/2/) for a server, but the client can only send one message and then the server will reply with a number.

Here is the code.

```
import socket
mySocket = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
mySocket.bind ( ( '', 2000 ) )
mySocket.listen ( 1 )
while True:
   channel, details = mySocket.accept()
   print 'We have opened a connection with', details
   print channel.recv ( 100 )
   channel.send ( 'Green-eyed monster.' )
   channel.close()
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is it that whenever the client sends a message to the server, it responds with a number?
2. How can I use sockets over the Internet, not over LAN?
3. Is there a way for me to have the server move data from client to client using sockets - somewhat like an [IM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_messaging) program.
4. I will most likely host this IM server for my friends on my Mac - will it work between OS's (Mac, PC)
5. Are there any good libraries to use for this? (I have heard that HTTP is great)
6. These lines of code are *really* confusing. How do they work?

   ```
   print channel.recv ( 100 )
   channel.send ( 'Green-eyed monster.' )
   ```
7. Also, when I close the server (using the red X), and reuse the port, it says this:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\****\Desktop\Python\Sockets\First Server\server.py",
   line 3, in <module>
   mySocket.bind ( ( '', 2003 ) )
   File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
   return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
   error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address
   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
   ```
8. Lastly, where are some good tutorials for me to understand this better?

Sorry for asking so many questions in the same post, but when I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764294/how-to-change-the-shutdown-message-for-windows-using-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764126/how-to-make-a-python-script-which-can-logoff-shutdown-and-restart-a-computer) people got mad with me for posting about similar problems in different problems.

Python version: Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research (over *several* hours) and have found some solutions to my issues!

**3:** Yes, There is a way to have the clients communicate with each other, *they just have to use the server!* You have to initialize an infinite loop on the server side, which will receive data and send it. This is how I solved the issue:

```
    while True:
        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(data)
        print data
        #To come out of the loop
    conn.close()
```

This program is part of a definition called **clientthread** which initializes all connections with clients. The "Actual" loop carries on the rest of the thread:

```
     while True:
        #Wait to accept a connection - blocking call
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        #display client information (IP address)
        print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

        #Start new thread takees 1st argument as a function name to be run, second
        #is the tuple of arguments to the function

        start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))
```

**4:** Yes, it will work between OS's. Sockets are *independent* of the platform.

**6:** That line of code is actually quite simple. The line `print channel.recv ( 100 )` tells the server to print the user input, up to 100 characters. The next line, `channel.send ( 'Green-eyed monster.' )` is simply telling the server to send out a message, `Green-eyed monster` to the client.

**7:** That error occurs because you cannot have more than one socket open per port. I would suggest using a line such as `s.close()` or `sys.exit()` at the end of your code, to close the port. Or you can simply choose another one!

**8:** There are some great tutorials out on the internet. One that teaches you the basics of sockets is [this](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/1/). Telnet was really confusing for me, so I discovered that in conjunction with [this](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Sockets-in-Python/2/) client one can create a customized client which is in fact much better.

If you have any questions, feel free to comment and I will try to answer.