# How to fix Error 61 (Mac) and Error 10061(Windows) using Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, windows, macos, sockets

I am currently attempting to create a basic LAN socket server, which works correctly when I use both the client and the server on the same computer. When I attempt to use the client and server on two computers (mac and windows) the connection is consistently refused on the client side. Here is the error that I got on my mac:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/*****/Desktop/Client V2.py", line 31, in <module>
s.connect((host, port))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

On my windows I had the same error, only the number was different. I have turned off windows firewall for both incoming and outgoing connections, and I am confused as to what the actual issue is. Here is the code that I had for my ports:

**Client**

```
#Get host and port info to connect
host = 'localhost'
port = input ("What is the PORT number?")
```

I am not sure if these lines are necessary, perhaps they are the root cause of the problem:

```
try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print "Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting"
    sys.exit()
```

And finally, the actual code that connects. (I called the socket `s`)
    s.connect((host, port))

**Server**

```
HOST = 'localhost' #Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces

PORT = input ("Enter the PORT number (1 - 10,000)")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Socket Created"

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error, msg:
    print "Bind failed. Error Code : " + str(msg[0]) + " Message " + str(msg[1])
    sys.exit()
print "Socket Bind Complete"


s.listen(10)
print "Socket now listening"
```

I am certain that I have done something really silly, but can someone please tell me what my mistake is (or if this is even possible cross-os). I already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784132/general-python-socket-questions-with-several-answers), but no one responded. I have several other questions there, and it would be great if someone could attempt to answer them.

Comment: Why would localhost work for two different machines?

Answer (score 1):

```
HOST = 'localhost' #Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
```

doesn't mean "all available interfaces" but only the local machine via a special interface only visible to programs running on the same computer.

```
HOST = '0.0.0.0' #Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
```

does mean all available network interfaces.  Of course you can also bind to a specific network interface, in that case you just enter its ip address in the field.

Comment: I made the changes in the comment and hostname. Why is it that `0.0.0.0` is the symbolic name, and not `localhost`. Does it even matter? What does "all available interfaces" even mean? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Well they're called that way by convention. All available interfaces means that a computer can very well have more than one network interfaces (eg modern server class computers often have 4 ethernet interfaces).  Binding a service to all interfaces (as indicated by 0.0.0.0) is not always desired - imagine on a computer has separate interfaces to serve the internal network and the internet you don't want say your accounting server to be accessible via the internet but you do want your public website available on both), and that's why you can bind either to all interfaces or just a specific one.

Comment: I think this misses another issue, that the code always specifies `localhost` and OP is complaining that his code doesn't work when trying to communicate between two machines.